# How to draw amount of blocks of the progressbar in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, progress-bar

Progressbar has a maximumm is 10.

So I need to draw ten block without fill color before running progress.

[image]

Edit: added code

```
Public Class MyProgressBar
Inherits ProgressBar

Public Sub New()
    Me.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
  For i as integer = 1 to 10
     Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
     Dim widthScale As Integer = Me.Width/10
     g.DrawRectangle(Pens,Me.Left+(i*widthScale ),Me.Top, Me.Width / 10, Me.Height)
    End For
End Sub
End Class
```

I try override OnPaint() but it's not working.

Comment: And what is your problem? What did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: I try override OnPaint(). But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do this. The simplest would be to create a transparent image of the boxes and put it on top of a regular progress bar.

Or you could create an array of text boxes, and play with their position, border and background until they look the way you want.

A more powerful way to do graphics is with the built-in [.net graphics object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.7.2). There's a brief introduction [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/gdi-graphics-in-visual-basic-net-3424305)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to a currently unanswerable question.